# Field of type long not being indexed with spring-data-neo4j

Tags: spring, indexing, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Exactly as the title says. I've created an `@NodeEntity` annotated POJO and in it I have a field that I want to use as an identifier that is a `long` that I would like to index and search around.

When I save my POJO using `neo4jTemplate` it saves okay, and I can see neo4j creating the index name for my Class, but when I attempt to query against the Index, I get nothing.

I've tried the field with both `int` and `long`, but neither seem to work. When querying, I've tried both `1`, `1l`, and `"1"` but none return my Node.

I can confirm that an index can be created with a Key/Value where the value is an `int` or a `long` and they work fine.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that in SDN primitives gets indexed as numerical, which has a special meaning in Lucene (the default index of choice for neo4j) and they need to be queries in a similar way to be found... namely with numerical range queries. I don't know how that would look in SDN, but by using org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery to create Query objects to search for ranges of primitives (for example int or long) those can be queried.

Comment: That worked. It is type sensitive, so if you save in the DB as int and you do a `NumericRangeQuery` of type long, it will return false, but as long as you get the type right it works.

Comment: I found a way to change this. I'm currently using SDN 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, not sure if it's also in 2.0.1-RELEASE, but on the `@Indexed` annotation there is a field, `numeric` which defaults to true, turning this off allows for exact and range query's.